# Why isn't this setInterval working?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

The code:

```
setInterval("doSomething()", 2000);
function doSomething(){alert('hi')}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PRff7/

I've been [reading about this](http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/JavaScript-setInterval-Function-JavaScript-Timing-Events.aspx) and I just can't get the example to work :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code isn't executing because of jsfiddle.  It wrapped your code in an onload handler, thus keeping `doSomething` out of the global namespace.  So when setTimeout tried to execute your code, it couldn't find `doSomething`.  Change jsfiddle to execute "no wrap", and all is well:  http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/PRff7/3/

If you don't wrap your call to `doSomething` in a string, it will also work because `setInterval` gets a direct reference to `doSomething` which is in the same scope. It doesn't need a global reference.

Comment: amazing answer. I kept seeing the examples on the internet with "" and I was wondering why so many of the examples were wrong, it was simply because they were pre-jQuery.

Comment: @Mohammad: It's not that they're pre-jQuery; it's that they're in the global scope.

Comment: @Mohammad - indeed SLaks is right.  This non-jQuery code would have the same issue: `window.onload = function(){ function doSomething() { ... } setInterval("doSomething()", 1000); };`

Comment: Thank you both, I'm going to learn about global variables next : )

Answer (score 3):

You need to change it to

```
setInterval(doSomething, 2000);
function doSomething(){alert('hi')}
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't pass a string to `setInterval`.

Instead, pass the function itself:

```
setInterval(doSomething, 1000);
```

Comment: Remove the () from doSomething.

Comment: @gilly3: Yes.  I actually had no idea what the problem was; congratulations for figuring it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to leave your code inline, and not to delegate it to some named function (especially if code consists of more than one command), use this:

```js
setInterval( function(){ alert('hi'); alert('hello') }, 2000);
```